# How to insert subdocument in meteor using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to meteor. I need to add a subdocument in Meteor users collection when a user signup. The code I used is:

```
Meteor.users.update({ "_id": user._id },
            {$push: { "rules": { "_id" : Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(), //// Create a new ObjectID
             "lineup_label_limit" : 1,
             "lineup_app_limit" : 5,
             "invite_count_limit" : 1 } }
            })
```

It doesn't works. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `new Mongo.ObjectID()._str` instead. But also, are you getting an error, or is it just not updating?

Comment: @forallepsilon: Thanks. Yes i am getting an error "update failed access denied" . I tried this code in the client side, but it is working in the server side.Will it work in the client side?

Comment: As per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407881/updating-meteor-users-from-client
you can only update the published field `username`, `emails`, and `profile` on the client. You can add the fields you desire into the `profile' field, for example.

Comment: @forallepsilon: Thank you again. I used the following method to solve this problem and it works for me,                                          Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {      
         user.rules = [ { "_id" : new Mongo.ObjectID()._str, "lineup_label_limit" : 1, "lineup_app_limit" : 5, "invite_count_limit" : 1 } ]
        return user;
    });