# Attempting to update Meteor.users results in "Access Denied"

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I am working on a Meteor project and I am trying to update a specific user's profile. However, I always receive

```
    update failed: Access denied
```

I have the user id stored in the variable user_id, and my code looks like

```
    Meteor.users.update({_id: user_id}, {$set: {'profile.participate_studies': updated_user_list}})
```

However, if I do

```
    Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {'profile.participate_studies': updated_user_list}})
```

The update works. This makes me think there is some issue with the id I have stored. Is there a difference between what Meteor.userId() returns and a string containing an id? I know the id is correct because I can access it in shell with the id.

I have looked at [Updating Meteor.users from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407881/updating-meteor-users-from-client), but I am not trying to update the edit the base user object. I really appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allowed to update your own profile, so when you do

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {
  $set: {'profile.participate_studies': updated_user_list}
})
```

You update your own profile (`Meteor.userId()` returns an id of currently logged in user).

And when you update profile of some other user, you receive and `Access denied` error.

You need to set `allow` rules for `Meteor.users`:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function(userId, user) {
    return true; 

    /**
     * Don't use `return true` in production!
     * You probably need something like this:
     * return Meteor.users.findOne(userId).profile.isAdmin;
     */
  }
});
```

Full documentation for allow rules: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow

---

***TIP:*** You can use shorthand for updating by id:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {...})
```